# Does antibodies get produced in female body against sperms?

Tags: immune-system, antibody, sexual-reproduction

Our immune system produces antibodies against any foreign particles entering our body.In female body  sperms are a foreign particle .Does females produce antibodies or some sort of chemical resistance against these sperms?If so how come sperms able to survive this?Is it because there a huge number of sperms entering female body?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisperm_antibodies Sperm can trigger antibodies production.Sperms are also killed by the low pH in the female genital tract